# Vue.js - separate CSS (SCSS) from the single *.vue file

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js, vuejs2

Default Vue.js concept is to have template, JS and styles together inside one *.vue file.

My question is: how to divide CSS / SCSS from *.vue files and get below structure:

```
components
-- componentA
---- componentA.vue
---- componentA.scss
-- componentB
---- componentB.vue
---- componentB.scss
-- componentC
---- componentC.vue
---- componentC.scss
```

Is there any good practice to create such project structure and build main/dist CSS via Webpack ? Any examples or Vue CLI templates?

Answer (score 6):

You can import the styles:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
    @import './foo.scss';
</style>

<script>
...
</script>
```

You will have to install [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) and [configure your webpack: vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/363).

Comment: Is there any automatic way to attach the SCSS file to the global / common CSS once *.scss file exists inside specific component folder (without need to add @import) ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you can look into preLoaders. Something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader

Comment: Does intellisense for variables in foo.scss work in the .Vue file? I tried in vscode and it does not work (but the scss is imported correctly)